# How to migrate IDA/HexRays database to the new version of the same application?

Tags: ida, hexrays

I have an .idb and PE file of an old version of an application. Now I want to transfer all knowledge to a new database for the new version of PE. How can I do this?

It seems that I need to compare all the functions and move the information if their contents match (the addresses may be different). How to do this?

It is clear that I need to calculate the hash from each function, find the intersections, and then compare the matched functions byte-to-byte. It's about whether there are ready-made tools for this?

Comment: @Biswapriyo typically, compilers generate code based on strict rules, not random.

Comment: @Biswapriyo compilation is a deterministic process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [bindiff](https://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html) for this purpose.

Another option will be to use [FLIRT](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/tech/flirt/in_depth.shtml), though I would prefer bindiff.